# How do I create a Like on an image using Facebook's Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to embed a Facebook photo album for a client, this is the first time I use the Facebook Graph API and I am a bit lost. I managed to fetch the images using this code (it is ugly, I confess, but for now I am only trying to make it work) :

```
<?
    $facebook_album = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/486769464721177/photos');
    $dataArr = json_decode($facebook_album,true);
    foreach($dataArr['data'] as $d){ 
        echo "<a href=".$d['link']." target='_blank'><img src=\"".$d['source']."\"></a>";
    }
?>
```

The thing now is that my client wants his visitors to be able to like these images individually. I thought about using the like button like so in the foreach loop :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<? print $d['link']?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

But it doesn't work whereas the $d['link'] for the link on the images works just fine.
Can anyone help out with this ? I read that it is possible to post a like on these objects using Open Graph but I have no clue on how to proceed in PHP to do so.

Thank you very much for your help !

---

So, I have read a lot here on many questions relative to my problems, and also on facebook's developers documentations.

I have come up with something that starts to work but it still is very clumsy.

Here is all my PHP :

```
<?
        require_once("php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = '##MyAppID##';
        $config['secret'] = '##MyAppSecret##';

        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $user_id=$facebook->getUser();
        if($facebook->getUser()) {
          // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
          // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
          try {
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                           'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                           )); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

          // No user, so print a link for the user to login
          // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
          // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
          // need to specify it here.
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

        }

        $facebook_album = $facebook -> api('486769464721177/photos');
        foreach($facebook_album['data'] as $d){ 
            ?>
            <div style="float:left;"><?  
            echo "<a href=".$d['link']." target='_blank'><img src=\"".$d['source']."\"></a>";
            echo count($d['likes']);
            ?><button><a href="https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?<?print ('access_token='.$access_token.'&method=POST&object='.$d['link']);?>?>">J'aime</a></button><?



            </div>
            <?
        }
    ?>
```

As you can see, I now ask for a user to be logged in with an App I created to get 'publish_actions' authorizations and so the access token. I have two problems now : First, is about the login. It works fine to log in if you are totally logged out of facebook. But if you are already logged in, there is a logout button, which is called by this line

```
echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
```

When the user click on this, the page reloads, the user still has an active session, but if he tries to go on the Facebook websites, he finds himself logged out. So what I would need here is a 'destroy session' rather than this logout button.

The other problem I have is this one : When the user is logged in, and his access token acquired, he should be able to like the objects called in the foreach loop. However, when he tries to do so, he gets this error from the Graph API :

```
    {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I am desperate for help here, I am sure that what I want to achieve is not complicated, but it's the first time I get my hands dirty in facebook's APIs and I am lost.

(If you would like to see it live : http://private.quentindelattre.ch/lab/vote.php)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The facebook like button is per webpage, if you specify a working webpage in the data-href property, clicking the like button will like the webpage that is specified.

If you want it to work, each of your images need to have their own, publicly accessible webpage, that will be given to the data-href parameter.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer.That's why I thought that using that bit as the href : $d['link']  would do the trick but it doesn't work...

Here is all my code : 

<?
 $facebook_album = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/486769464721177/photos');
 $dataArr = json_decode($facebook_album,true);
 foreach($dataArr['data'] as $d){ 
  ?><div style="float:left;"><?  
     echo "<a href=".$d['link']." target='_blank'><img src=\"".$d['source']."\"></a>";
     ?>
     <div data-href="<? print $d['link']?>"></div>
  </div>
  <?
 }
?>

Comment: Note that if your site is tested locally and unaccessible from facebook, the social buttons and comment boxes will not work fully as intended.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks for that, I will try it from a server and let you know !

Comment: Wow... I get weird error messages from my server...

Can anyone help me ?

http://private.quentindelattre.ch/lab/album.php

Comment: It looks like it's not including a file properly for some reason, you might need to open a different question.

Comment: I resolved the errors messages so now, you can check out what I'm going on about the like button who behaves weirdly.

Comment: What I mean is that, the link on every images work just fine, but if you try to like one of them, at first the button triggers, and immediately comes back to its original count...

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what the problem is. What I do in this page is that I give a link to be liked which is itself a Facebook page, and I think the Like Button doesn't allow that at all. So what I would need is to post a like on the Graph object I am displaying in this page. I don't know if it is quite clear...